# Calculating all combinations from arrays AND (arrays OR floats)

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, combinatorics

**Context:** My question comes from needing to iterate different `np.arange` arrays. The main **motivation** is to calculate all the possible combinations between the arrays, let's say `a`, `b`, `c`, `x`, `y`, `z` where the last 3 (`x`, `y`, `z`) can be arrays OR floats.

The **reason behind** is that every combination can be evaluated then in equations. Floats OR values are considered because `x`, `y`, `z` represent parameters (that can be fixed or considered to have errors) and `a`, `b`, `c` are variables. This is useful when wanting to evaluate a set of differential equations solutions. In a mathematical context some would say "the raison d'être is to explore the space of parameters".

To calculate every possible combination I know I can iterate using for-loops. The problem arises when considering the exceptions: as `x`, `y`, `z` can be lists "L" or numbers "N", I find the cases:

```
#Different combinations:

options=[['N',1],['L',2]]
for i in options:
    for j in options:
        for k in options:
            print(i[0]+j[0]+k[0]+' w/ total combinations: '+str(2*2*2*i[1]*j[1]*k[1]))
```

which are NNN, NNL, NLL, NLN, LNL, LLN, LNN, LLL. I've also calculated the length of the resulting possibilities, for the case of `len()=2` arrays.

**What is the code doing?:** calculating every possibility. If there's a number instead of a list (or array) it's not iterated but appended constantly through every possibility for the other variables that do "change".

**But** the problem is: considering each case separatedly is unefficent and messy code. **Question**: how could I do it in a more general and compacted way?

**You can check the code here**:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import numbers

a = np.random.uniform(1,10,2)
b = np.random.uniform(1,10,2)
c = np.random.uniform(1,10,2)

w=[36] #this is a len(w)=1 list only to manage exceptions, but is equivalent to have a number instead of a list/array.

x = np.random.normal(2,1e-1,2) #This could be a float
y = np.random.normal(3,1e-1,2) #This could be a float
z = np.random.normal(4,1e-1,2) #This could be a float


#Now interate

def iter_func(args):

    returned_array = [] #this is the output list-of-lists with all the combinations.

    a,b,c,x,y,z = args #numbers or arrays; variables or parameters (w/ or w/o errors in a mathematical context)
    
    for avals in a:
        for bvals in b:
            for cvals in c:
            
                if isinstance(x,np.ndarray)==True:                
                    
                    for xvals in x:
                        
                        if isinstance(y,np.ndarray)==True:
                        
                            for yvals in y:
                                
                                if isinstance(z,np.ndarray)==True:
                        
                                    for zvals in z:
                                        returned_array.append([avals,bvals,cvals,xvals,yvals,zvals])
                                
                                elif isinstance(z,numbers.Real)==True or isinstance(z,list)==True and len(z)==1:
                                        returned_array.append([avals,bvals,cvals,xvals,yvals,z])
                        
                        elif isinstance(y,numbers.Real)==True or isinstance(y,list)==True and len(y)==1:
                            returned_array.append([avals,bvals,cvals,xvals,y,z])
                            
                elif isinstance(x,numbers.Real)==True or isinstance(x,list)==True and len(x)==1:
                    
                    if isinstance(y,np.ndarray)==True:
                       
                            for yvals in y:
                                
                                if isinstance(z,np.ndarray)==True:
                        
                                    for zvals in z:
                                        returned_array.append([avals,bvals,cvals,x,yvals,zvals])
                                
                                elif isinstance(z,numbers.Real)==True or isinstance(z,list)==True and len(z)==1:
                                        returned_array.append([avals,bvals,cvals,x,yvals,z])
                        
                    elif isinstance(y,numbers.Real)==True or isinstance(y,list)==True and len(y)==1:
                        
                        if isinstance(z,np.ndarray)==True:
                        
                            for zvals in z:
                                returned_array.append([avals,bvals,cvals,x,y,zvals])
                                
                        elif isinstance(z,numbers.Real)==True or isinstance(z,list)==True and len(z)==1:
                            returned_array.append([avals,bvals,cvals,x,y,z])
                        
    return returned_array

#Now I'm testing different possibilities

#Case test: last 3 are lists of numbers
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,w,w,w])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 1: NNN
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,w[0],w[0],w[0]])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 2: NNL
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,w[0],w[0],z])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 3: NLN 
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,w[0],y,w[0]])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 4: NLL   
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,w[0],y,z])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 5: LNN    
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,x,w[0],w[0]])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 6: LNL    
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,x,w[0],z])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 7: LLN    
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,x,y,w[0]])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')

#Case 8: LLL   
returned_array = iter_func([a,b,c,x,y,z])
print('total combinations: '+str(len(returned_array)))
for i in returned_array:
    print(i)
print('\n')
```

with output:

```
total combinations: 8
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, [36], [36], [36]]
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, [36], [36], [36]]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, [36], [36], [36]]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, [36], [36], [36]]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, [36], [36], [36]]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, [36], [36], [36]]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, [36], [36], [36]]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, [36], [36], [36]]


total combinations: 8
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 36]
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 36]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 36]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 36]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 36]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 36]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 36]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 36]


total combinations: 16
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.8336495994988162, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.8336495994988162, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.741768057298594, 5.295916749347686, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 4.929950792386235, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.8501788450044114]
[2.741768057298594, 9.869611330430935, 9.493663046965622, 36, 36, 3.895647492990764]
```

**Q:** is this called "variable-depth for-loops", "nested for-loops"? Any comment on this would be highly appreciated.

I'm not very familiar with Python but **Q:** I think it could be done in a simplier way. What would you suggest? Any hint? Maybe a way to do it with pandas, numpy or in a big list comprehension? (I do not really know if possible).
I apologize if the question is vague. I'd be happy if you suggest *anything to make the question clearer*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question and your code are both fairly confused, but let's attempt to dig into it anyway.

The return type of your function is a big, crazy mix of Python native sequences and Numpy arrays, when it should be a single two-dimensional Numpy array.

`iter_func` does a poor job of explaining what this is supposed to accomplish, but I'm leaving it for now.

Delete all of your `isinstance` checks and replace them with a type-coerce via `np.atleast_1d`.

Don't write your code to require six arguments; accept an arbitrary number of arguments.

Delete basically all of your code. Recognise that this is a Cartesian product, and whereas Numpy doesn't have a built-in for this, [this is a solved problem on the internet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points).

Add PEP484 type hints, write a wrapper for the above SO answer that accommodates your lists, scalars and arrays, and we have

```
from typing import Union, Sequence

import numpy as np
from numbers import Real


def cartesian_product(*arrays: np.ndarray) -> np.ndarray:
    """
    See
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11144513/cartesian-product-of-x-and-y-array-points-into-single-array-of-2d-points
    """
    la = len(arrays)
    dtype = np.result_type(*arrays)
    arr = np.empty([len(a) for a in arrays] + [la], dtype=dtype)
    for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrays)):
        arr[..., i] = a
    return arr.reshape(-1, la)


def iter_func(
    *args: Union[Real, Sequence[Real], np.ndarray],
) -> np.ndarray:
    return cartesian_product(*(
        np.atleast_1d(a) for a in args
    ))
```

Comment: Thanks much for the attempt and effort! This works exactly as I expected and allows me to study about Cartesian products. I've redacted the question again aiming for a better explanation. Also, I think that I could have converted numbers into constant arrays and use for loops with a break (to iterate only 1 time) if the 1st element of a constant array is equivalent to the 2nd . This might be simplier than my first attempt. Should I forget this? What do you think? A cartesian product is the standard?

Comment: _Should I forget this?_ Yeah, probably. `for`-loops are generally inappropriate to use with Numpy arrays when vectorised solutions exist. The loop still exists, but it's done for you in a compiled library that runs much faster.

Comment: Just asking for more information: if I need to impose a condition over every combination should I write it indented inside `for i, a in enumerate(np.ix_(*arrays))`? e.g., `if sum() > 20` discard the list, else append the list+result of `sum()`. Again, I could iterate over possible combinations but I suspect this is not the fastest way. Should I open a new question?

Comment: _should I write it indented inside [a for loop]?_ No. You should invest some research time into how Numpy uses vectorised logic and slicing. _Should I open a new question?_ Yes; though if it's "how do I filter in Numpy", it would belong on StackOverflow and not CodeReview.